# Internet Explorer 7 jQuery Validate

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate

can someone please suggest a better means to accomplish what i'm doing below.  The commented out return works in all browsers besides after IE7.  I know this is totally ghetto, but this is the only way I've gotten it to work because IE7 can't parse json that I know of.  It seems like this is just one thing piling up on top of the other when I use webforms and jquery Validation.  I can't get my webservice to reply if the values are in the query string so I have to add rules manually.  i.e. /webservices/ipmws.asmx/SiteValid?tbSiteName=WHATEVER....  If that would work perhaps all this wouldn't be required?

Thanks in advance.

```
$('#form2').validate();
    $("#tbSiteName").rules("add", {
        remote: function () {
            var r = {
                url: "/webservices/ipmws.asmx/SiteValid",
                type: "POST",
                data: "{'tbSiteName': '" + $("#tbSiteName").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) {
                    var str = data.split(':');
                    return str[1].substring(0, str[1].length -1)
                    //return (JSON.parse(data)).d;
                }
            }
            return r;
        },
        messages: {
            remote: "The site code is either not present or invalid."
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery's $.parseJSON() method?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I am using parseJSON() in IE7.